# Democratic governments seizing financial assets during financial crisis?

Tags: government, financial-crisis

I was reading about the Greek haircut last year when the EU along with the Greek government forced bond holders to accept a 75% haircut on their assets.  I remember Germany doing something similar at the end of WW2.  I was wondering if this is perhaps more common then previously thought?

Does anyone have anymore examples of democratic governments directly seizing or devaluing financial assets?

Comment: [Cyprus](http://www.guardian.co.uk/business/2013/mar/22/eurozone-crisis-cyprus-bailout-russia-vote)..?

Comment: Depends on your definition of "seizing or devaluing financial assets". Plenty of countries combined strong inflationary measures with restriction on converting country's currency to other currencies (Russia comes to mind as one example, in 1990s); which has the same effect.

Comment: No I'm not talking about indirect inflationary methods but rather direct actions.

Comment: @user357320 - people are screwed either way, as the old joke goes :) But it's your question so you set the rules.

Comment: How it depends on whether a country democratic or not?

Comment: @Anixx I guess in case if you have the right and possibility to change the governing party in the normal voting interval, then it counts as democratic.

Comment: @CsBalazsHungary my question was how seizing assets depends on whether a country democratic.

Comment: @Anixx Ok, that is a good question. Seizing anything is an autocratic action. Except if those things came from crime activities directly. In my answer I gave three examples where a democratic country seized something (or "stole" value). In a democratic country the power origins from the people, and they have the right to take it away. And still the government took away something from their "bosses". That is the interesting side of this question.

Comment: how far back in history?

Answer (score 6):

I can mention three direct devaluation and seizure from my readings and memory where Democratic countries involved.

- first one: Hungary in 1996, [Bokros Package](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bokros_package) contained direct devaluation
  of Hungarian Forints, so all savings lost value instantly. I think
  this method is not unique in history, but sadly I can't mention
  other.
- second one: Recently in Hungary, 2011. The government seized all the private
  pension funds. Those who wanted to keep it, were forced to make a
  disclaimer, they want to keep it. The goverment treatened the
  population: the disclaimers will receive no state pension even if
  they pay the related tax. Only 3% kept their savings (including me).
  I am sorry, I can't really provide English sources, just a [Hungarian
  one](http://hu.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mag%C3%A1nnyugd%C3%ADjp%C3%A9nzt%C3%A1r). The private pension payments are still held back by
  government regardless if you made the disclaimer. The savings' 89% by now gone on ad-hoc expenses.
- third one: [Seizure of private gold in 1933](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executive_Order_6102) in US, an interesting
  subject indeed. The given value was lower than the gold value itself.

Answer (score 1):

It's a small (not a county wide example), but US Government [forced the bondholders of GM to accept a haircut that was contrary to capital structure of the company](http://www.nypost.com/p/news/opinion/opedcolumnists/model_corruption_ttyHIpNuoQRwVTkBZuhHeM) (in order to give more of the post-bankruptcy assets to the labor union).

More specifically, unsecured bondholder claimants received roughly 10% (90% haircut) on their securities - they got 10% equity in new GM for ~$27B of old GM liabilities, and could not sell till the post-IPO price fell by ~1/3 - meaning, it was even lower than 10%, more ~5-8%.

In contrast, by Obama's "Car tzar" insistence, UAW got what was estimated to be 50-60% on their liabilities ([src](http://latimesblogs.latimes.com/money_co/2009/04/general-motors-corps-latest-debt-for-equity-swap-proposal-is-barely-out-of-the-box-and-critics-already-have-declared-it-a.html)), **almost 10x more - while one of the main principles of bancruptcy law is that similarly senior debtholders must be given the same treatment**.

Comment: Not from me!  Thanks for suggestion, I had forgotten about GM.  Also wasn't something similar at Washington Mutual?

Comment: @user357320 - you're quite right. Actually someone made a parallel between WaMu and Cyprus: http://www.openmarket.org/2013/03/20/what-cyprus-initially-got-right-remembering-the-2008-wamu-capital-run/

Comment: Just to be clear it wasn't the union that got the preferential treatment, but a fund, administered by the union, used to provide medical benefits to retired workers. That's a big difference.

Comment: @DJClayworth - The trust is still part of the union, for the benefit of union members. The distinction you are making is technically correct, but I don't see how it's meaningful in this context - it benefits ALL union members who are retired now or will retire later and will be paid for their expenses out of that trust.

Comment: So it's for the benefit of the workers, not the union. You seemed to be implying that the money was for the benefit of the union itself. That's a big difference - as big as the difference between "more money for the American People" and "more money for the American Government"

Comment: @DJClayworth - bad example, incidentally. More money for American people=>more tax revenue>more money for the American Government :)... Seriously, it's a benefit for UNION workers, not just "workers". And this has absolutely nothing to do with the substance of the fact, that basic bancruptcy rules were severely violated by treating some unsecured debt different from another, for political reasons.

Comment: I've seen no evidence it wasn't for ALL workers. In any case, what you wrote substantially misrepresented the facts.

Comment: Let's also not forget that the GM bondholders always had the ability to decline the offer. This wasn't a compulsory deal.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is of a partial government debt default. **Russia** and **Argentina** both defaulted on their debts in recent history. (So did **Iceland**, in relation to government-guaranteed foreign savings accounts of its bad banks, in the opinion of the governments representing those savers - but the EFTA Court ruled that no such obligation existed under the circumstances.)

Incidentally, Russia is an awkward example for the economic school of thought known as Modern Monetary Theory (or MMT), which states that any country that controls its own currency and issues debt in its own currency cannot go bankrupt. In particular, key MMT advocate and financier Warren Mosler was not expecting the Russian default, and lost money because of it. He now states that Russia defaulted on its debts for "political", not "economic" reasons. (I would be interested to read evidence to back this up.)

Comment: Re: Iceland.  The saving accounts weren't government guaranteed. (EFTA ruling)